# Lenovo t400 shows black screen. How to fix?

Tags: windows-10, thinkpad, black-screen-of-death

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad t400 laptop. I Updated antivirus and system asked to restart the computer. I just turned of the laptop and slept. When I turned it up in the morning, light of the screen was dim and just showing Lenovo and windows10 logo in dim light. I am able to go into the BIOS. Charging and battery Indicator LEDs are also not working. I tried to auto repair it and tried to restore but it failed. Not getting any clue, what is wrong with it..

Comment: What antivirus you have updated? Add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem a few years back with a Lenovo Y510p and I was ready to send it back for repairs and I noticed there was still my SD card in the reader. I took it out and everything was working perfectly. So if I were you I would first try unplugging all flash drives and emptying the card reader.

If the problem persists, try to create a bootable flash drive with some kind live OS, just to make sure the PC itself is ok. You might need to enable USB in legacy mode in BIOS and also change the boot order to actually boot from the flash drive. If this OS works, it's probably broken HDD or corrupt OS installation. You could attempt a windows reinstall and if it fails it's most definitely the HDD.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have followed your all instructions but these did not work. I reinstalled windows 10 and now I am able to use it but still screen is black. Computer starts with dim lighted screen till now  and I can see the screen using a torch or an external brighter light. Further, I can use it fully but just getting dim lighted screen. One more thing, when I connect my laptop with external monitor, I can see everything clearly as normal.

Comment: Is the screen dimmed while you are in BIOS as well? If that is the case then it probably means that the LCD backlight is broken and you will need a screen replacement. I checked ebay and the lcd for your particular laptop costs around 70 dollars. While screen replacements are not the easiest repairs they are still manageable with just a screwdriver.

Comment: Yes, the screen was dimmed when I entered in BIOS as well.  I am going to visit a laptop  repairing  shop today. Thank you for your help.